# How do I write a file path which include a regular expression

Tags: linux, shell

Depending on the system I am working on, there might be 2 different possible paths (mutually exclusive):

```
System1: /tmp/aword/foo
System2: /tmp/bword/foo
```

I am supposed to echo something into the `foo` file regardless of which system I encounter (through a shell script).

How do I include a regular expression within the path itself, to take the correct (existent) path?

somethings I have tried:

```
#doesn't work
echo Hello > /tmp/(a|b)word/foo
#doesn't work
echo Hello > /tmp/[a|b]word/foo
```

is there a way of doing this without having to include a test before this which tests for path existence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it literally is `aword` and `bword` and you know that only one of them exists, you can use

```
echo 'Hello' > /tmp/[ab]word/foo
```

This is a shell pattern and [documented in the Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) or the [POSIX sh spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_13_01).

If, however, both paths exist, Bash will complain with

```
-bash: [ab]word: ambiguous redirect
```

Comment: Note that globs are not regular expressions. (But this is probably what the OP is looking for.)

Comment: Thanks, this was it. Completely forgot about shell globbing. Tested with both paths existing (not a usecase for me) but I got: `shel.sh: line 4: /tmp/[ab]word/foo: ambiguous redirect`

Comment: @user2883071 Right, that's what the error would say, let me update that.